# Create a bootstrap row that has two col-**-6, then inside the second col-**-6 put another two so it stacks. How do I make it stack?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I kind of have it working though it could still fit on a screen without the two `col-**-6` stacking. This is basically what I want: https://prnt.sc/19393xt
Each color represents a `col-**-6`. That's basically what I want, but have it stay that way no matter what size the browser window is. I use `col-xxl-6` but just putting my browser in full screen mode, it's already not stacked.

```
<div class="row row-align">
    <div style="background-color: skyblue;" class="col-6">
        <img style="width: 100px; height: 100px;" src="files/placeholder.png">
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
        <div class="row row-align">
            <div style="background-color: grey;" class="col-xxl-6">
                <p>PlaceHolder</p>
            </div>
            <div style="background-color: limegreen;" class="col-xxl-6">
                <p>PlaceHolder</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have no intention of keeping the div background colors, just for visualization.

To draw it out, this is basically what I want, but for all screensize (so it doesn't adjust: https://prnt.sc/193bcso

Comment: Are you saying you want this? https://codeply.com/p/5eD3EfYnqE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you should replace `.col-xxl-6` by something defining the true width you want for mobile device like : `.col-12`

In bootstrap, when you use a `.col-x-yy` class, it works for all bigger screens than your `yy` breakpoint. So if you're using `.col-12`, your div will use 12 rows for all screen sizes

In addition, as @Zim did, you could add a `.h-100` class to you nested `.row` to make your columns with the same height.

It could look like that :

```
<div class="row row-align">
    <div style="background-color: skyblue;" class="col-6">
        <img style="width: 100px; height: 100px;" src="files/placeholder.png">
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 ">
        <div class="row row-align h-100">
            <div style="background-color: grey;" class="col-12">
                <p>PlaceHolder</p>
            </div>
            <div style="background-color: limegreen;" class="col-12">
                <p>PlaceHolder</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To understand Bootstrap one needs to look at how it's built.  Spend some time with the [source on Github](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap) and when you come across "strange" behaviours have a look at the source that generates the class.

For your question there are a few things to remember:

- BS columns are spilt into 12 columns [default compile], where each column is " 100% / 12 " in width.  It's important to remember that the `.col-x` classes only define the width as percentages of their parent class.
- BS is mobile first.  So if you want a behaviour for mobiles then just use the base classes.

For your requirement you will need to create a structure like this:

```
ROW (#1)
  COL-6 {50% of Row 1}
    (Skyblue)

  COL-6 {50% of Row 1}
    ROW (#2) <- this will exist inside the 2nd col

      COL-12 {100% of Row 2 !!, so nothing left, next one will wrap}
        (Grey)
      COL-12 {100% of Row 2 again, so will wrap to the next line, still inside row 2}
        (LimeGreen)
```

The simplified HTML will thus be:

```html
<div class="row">
  <div style="background-color: skyblue;" class="col-6">
    Placeholder
  </div>
  <div class="col-6">
    <div class="row">
      <div style="background-color: grey;" class="col-12">
        PlaceHolder
      </div>
      <div style="background-color: limegreen;" class="col-12">
        PlaceHolder
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```